# How to connect speakers for Android Things without HDMI

Tags: raspberry-pi, android-things

I have an android app that outputs sound normally on a phone. I also put it into an android device and can hear audio on tv through HDMI cable. I also have an android things app that moves a servo and can put audio on the tv, also working as expected.

What I can't do is get audio from the audio jack, which would be my preferred option since I want something without a display.

I have lots of logcat entries saying everything is normal and sound is not failing, but other than that I can't rule out if it's an OS capability that's turned off (there's no mention in release notes), something that needs to be tuned into config.txt, whether I need extra lines of code, or it is muted.

I'm assuming audio is not getting to the jack at all. I know that the Raspberry pi 3 b audio jack also carries video, and I've tried to tap into every combination of its pins without success, both using a cable splitter and putting cables on the pins of the connector directly on the board. I'm also assuming that one of the exposed pins under the board carries audio only. Though I'd be grateful if someone could clarify which has left / right channel, even if tested on Raspbian or other OSs.

As seen in following logs, audio focus is ok and SoundPool.play never return 0 (as showin in line that says `RESULT === 8`):

```
02-04 02:08:28.617 694-1722/com.example.androidthings.simplepio I/SoundEngine: Ask for focus
02-04 02:08:28.653 408-822/system_process I/MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from uid/pid 10025/694 clientId=android.media.AudioManager@f4664becom.example.androidthings.simplepio.audio.SoundEngine$1@c9ef91f req=3 flags=0x0
02-04 02:08:28.654 694-1722/com.example.androidthings.simplepio I/SoundEngine: Ask for focus and GOT it
02-04 02:08:28.655 694-1722/com.example.androidthings.simplepio W/SoundEngine: ********* RESULT === 8
02-04 02:08:28.656 408-420/system_process I/MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from uid/pid 10025/694 clientId=android.media.AudioManager@f4664becom.example.androidthings.simplepio.audio.SoundEngine$1@c9ef91f
02-04 02:08:28.656 694-1722/com.example.androidthings.simplepio I/SoundEngine: release focus
```

Comment: if you unplug the hdmi do you get any sound out of the audio jack?

Comment: No, nothing changes. Also booted with and without hdmi

Comment: Can you provide more information on the speaker you are using with the 3.5mm jack? Is it powered?

Comment: One is(internal battery) , one isn't (earphones) . Should I expect any of them to perform better?

Comment: The RPi amp is pretty weak, so a powered speaker would be preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed in the [Raspberry Pi overlay documentation](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/overlays/README#L934)

> 2) The onboard analogue audio output uses both PWM channel

So you can't use PWM to drive a servo and play sounds thru the onboard Audio simultaneously.

A few options are possible:

- try the USB audio support announced in [Developer Preview 2](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html#developer_preview_2)
- file [a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Things%20feature%20request) to add support for I2S in the Peripheral IO API.

Comment: wow, so much information in a short reply. I didn't know about a) the pwm channel, b) developer preview 2 existed already c) it had support for audio USB. But what made me happier is that they have an NDK GPIO api.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue sending audio to AUX port while the HDMI port is connected just for video output.

But, the solution that worked for me is, I first deployed my AndroidThings app onto RasPi and connected AUX port to test the audio, then I connected the HDMI to test the video out. In this sequence, everything worked both audio from AUX port and Video from HDMI.